# Restrict editing some post custom fields - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

In my website there is a master admin and some editors.

Each editor can edit and fill some custom fields too (meta boxes added by `Meta Box` plugin APIs) but I need to restrict editing and showing some custom fields to that group but didn't found anything related to this topic.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two free plugins that will work together to accomplish this, and more...

The first plugin is Advanced Custom Fields:  http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Advanced Custom Fields lets you create and assign groups of custom fields to specific user roles or post types.

The second plugin is the Members plugin which extends and allows customization/creation of user roles: http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ .

How it works. Use the Members plugin to create a new user role with the same (or whatever you like) permissions as Editor, call them 'Editors Plus'.  Then use Advanced Custom Fields to create a custom field group that only 'Editors Plus' can access. IE: Show this field group if: 'User', 'is equal to', 'Editor Plus'. All of it happens via easy GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Register a new role with help of this link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

and then apply authentication to this whatever you want.

thanks.

Comment: that privileges are so general! what I want is something customize!

Comment: you can stop showing & saving values posted by that users in metaboxes, but in this case you have to set up this in function.php by making an array containing a list of these type of authors.